# syntax used to type cast date(data type_ to integer in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want convert `Date` data type to `Integer`, i have tried to type cast the date(data type) to integer by using `::INT`, its not working.

I have got the following error

> ERROR:  column "date" is of type integer but expression is of type
>   date HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: want to convert 1/1/2019 to 112,019

Comment: We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, please edit your question to include your current query as it seems to be causing the issue. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for reference. Please however don't use screenshots, instead copy the text of your query and include it in your question.

Comment: Why there must be comma in there?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

```
replace(your_date::varchar, '/', '')::integer
```

Full example:

```
select replace(now()::date::varchar, '-', '')::integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TO_CHAR` function with [FM prefix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html)   and then cast it to Integer.

```
select to_char(date_column,'FMddFMmmYYYY')::INT as dateint FROM  t
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0a78a5560dcbaa3c7620de5052b21354)